# I want to sync my local database with the one online

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2, synchronization, replication

I want to sync my local database with the one online after a certain time I am using sql server Management 2008 r2 the purpose is to open reports online  so that the client can check it from anywhere  any suggestions  to do this.
I want to sync the local database with the one online after a certain time some technique such as mirroring, duplication or peer to peer replication can some one elaborate which will be the best method to perform this task or any other solution that you recommend to do so.

Comment: Maybe some more details would be nice, please edit question and check : http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymmetricDS is capable of synchronizing these databases.   It will keep them in sync in near real time depending how frequently you schedule the push and/or pull jobs (default is 1 min).  It is open source but also has a professional version depending on your needs

[SymmetricDS Open Source](http://symmetricds.org)

[SymmetricDS Professional](http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview)

Comment: thanks man can you provide me some link from where i can get help how to use this.....

Comment: Professional Documentation

http://www.jumpmind.com/downloads/symmetricds/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html

Comment: Open Source Documentation
http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html

Comment: There is also a 30 day free trial for the Professional, the Professional has a web based interface and some wizards to step you through the initial configuration.  Good Luck!

Comment: Thank You very much....For this support